# Cocos2d js touch events

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm building an app in cocos2d-js, and I've got a problem with listening to keyboard events. I expect a method called setKeyboardEnabled to exists but when I call it i get an error that setKeyboardEnabled is not a function, Am I missing something?

```
var AnimationLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
ctor : function() {
    this._super();
    this.setKeyboardEnabled(true);
},


onKeyDown : function(key) {
   cc.log("action");
}
...
...
)}
```

The same thing happens when I try to listen to touch events.

Comment: I saw post saying that this method is no longer available here http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/looking-for-setkeyboardenabled-substitute/9744

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Cocos2D v3 the way events are handled has changed. For a proper explanation of the whole system you should read [New event manager in Cocos2d-Html5 v3.0](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/new-event-manager-in-cocos2d-html5-v3-0/11637).

In short, if you used to have:

```
var AnimationLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    ctor : function() {
        this._super();
        this.setKeyboardEnabled(true);
    },

    onKeyDown : function(key) {
       cc.log("action");
    }
    ...
    ...
)}
```

You have to turn it into something like:

```
var AnimationLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    ctor : function() {
        this._super();

        cc.eventManager.addListener({
            event: cc.EventListener.KEYBOARD,
            onKeyDown : function(key) {
                cc.log("action");
            }
        }, this);
    },        

    ...
    ...
)}
```

This can sound a bit complicated at first, but this new mechanism allows you to attach these event listeners to any kind of `cc` node, not just layers. So for example you could do something like this to make a Sprite fade when the mouse is above it:

```
var hoverHandler = cc.EventListener.create({
    event: cc.EventListener.MOUSE,
    onMouseMove: function (event) {
      var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
      var locationInNode = target.convertToNodeSpace(event.getLocation());
      var s = target.getContentSize();
      var rect = cc.rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);

      if (cc.rectContainsPoint(rect, locationInNode)) {
        cc.log("It's hovering! x = " + locationInNode.x + ", y = " + locationInNode.y);
        target.opacity = 180;
        return true;
      } else {
        target.opacity = 255;
        return false;
      }
  }
});

var MyLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        var mySpriteThatFadesWhenHovered = cc.Sprite.create(...);
        this.addChild(mySpriteThatFadesWhenHovered);

        cc.eventManager.addListener(hoverHandler.clone(), mySpriteThatFadesWhenHovered );
    }
)}
```

Comment: Thanks, this way of handling user events seems to give more flexibility.

Comment: Yep, notice how I didn't even bother to try and write how that hover effect would be coded in v2.3, it's just too much work for doing something so simple. 
PS: if you are satisfied with it, remember to mark my post as the answer so future searchers can find it easily!